# HDD isn't re-allocating sectors

Tags: hard-drive, smart, bad-sectors

When a drive has bad sectors, I usually partition around it leaving 50~100 MB on either side of the bad area. I rarely go through SMART data. But this time when I was going through it I noticed this(Pictures).

If I am interpreting it right, the RAW values show that(correct me if I'm wrong):

- Disk1 has 1 bad sector, but re-allocated sector count is 0.
- Disk2 has 0 pending and 0x248 (73 bytes?) bad sectors, that were re-allocated previously.

**The question is:**

- If both the hard drives show 100/100/36 for Re-allocated sector count, then why isn't Disk1 allocating the bad sector to a backup sector?
- Did this disk come without any backup sectors?
- Why is Re-allocated sector count zero if in fact any backups were used and they ran out?
- Is there a software to do this manually, incase this harddrive's firmware isn't capable of re-allocating?

**Disk 1:**
[image]

**Disk 2:**
[image]

Comment: If you are getting uncorreactable sectors, then that disk, already used its backup sectors.

Comment: yes, but why would the disk smart say re-allocated sector count: 0? does it actually mean remaining re-allocatable sectors have run out? that would make sense. it's counting in reverse.